# InputStream не работает на некоторых устройствах

Tags: java, android

Столкнулся с проблемой. Строка 'InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();' на некоторых устройствах возвращает исключение, вроде как нет соединения. Хотя в другой активности e-mail отправляется без проблем. Недуг проявляется только на 2ух устройствах из 7ми. В эмуляторе тоже все работает хорошо.
Кусок кода:

'''

```
protected Void doInBackground() {
                int i = 0;
                int j = 0;

                try {
                    URL url = new URL("ссылка_на_файл");
                    InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(bis);
                    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
                    Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.iterator();

                    while (rows.hasNext()) {
                        Row row = rows.next();
                        Iterator<Cell> cells = row.iterator();
                        while (cells.hasNext()) {
                            Cell cell = cells.next();
                            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                                case STRING:
                                    str = cell.getStringCellValue();
                                    price[i][j] = str;
                                    str = "";
                                    break;
                                case BLANK:
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    str = "" + cell.getNumericCellValue();
                                    price[i][j] = str;
                                    str = "";
                                    break;
                            }
                            j++;
                        }
                        j = 0;
                        i++;
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i("LOG", "Нет файла");
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i("LOG", "Error");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i("LOG", "Нет соединения");
                }
                return null;
            }
```

'''

Comment: URL полностью напишите

Comment: Разобрался, в существующем исключении оставил только строку с URL, и в нем сделал еще один try, в котором InputStream.